# svn: listing the revs of files in a directory

Tags: svn, revision-history

Suppose I have this directory:

```
foo.c            // last changed rev = 4800
bar.c            // last changed rev = 4074
baz.c            // last changed rev = 4122
```

Is there any easy way using the svn command-line tools to obtain the following list or something like it?

```
4800 foo.c
4074 bar.c
4122 baz.c
```

I know I can do it by running `svn log -l 1 foo.c` and parsing the results, but that's a pain if there are a lot of files. ([Websvn](http://www.websvn.info/) lists this information in its display, but I'm not sure where to look in the source code.)

---

Hmm. `svn status --verbose` works great for a working copy, but not for checking a repository URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aha, found it myself:

```
svn ls --verbose http://myserver/myrepo/mydir
```

Answer (score 0):

```
svn help ls
...
usage: list [TARGET[@REV]...]
...
With --verbose, the following fields will be shown for each item:

    Revision number of the last commit
```